# Как загрузить cookie в selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

У меня есть cookie формата:

```
sfwefwe=0d6e941b3815079247b9069e3111bf05; xf_session=dabb9d85f436511c910c1205b22392c4; _ga=GA1.1.195811485.1653158493; xf_is_not_mobile=1; _ym_uid=1653158493674995086; _ym_d=1653158493; _ym_isad=1; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; _ga_J7RS527GFK=GS1.1.1653158492.1.1.1653161341.0
```

Как я могу конвертировать их в JSON формат используя Python?
Вообще мне нужно загрузить эти куки в selenium webdriver.
Буду вам очень благодарен если поможете.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is the site of the Russian-speaking SO community, please translate your question into Russian.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> cookies=map(lambda x: x.split('='), 'sfwefwe=0d6e941b3815079247b9069e3111bf05; xf_session=dabb9d85f436511c910c1205b22392c4; _ga=GA1.1.195811485.1653158493; xf_is_not_mobile=1; _ym_uid=1653158493674995086; _ym_d=1653158493; _ym_isad=1; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; _ga_J7RS527GFK=GS1.1.1653158492.1.1.1653161341.0'.split('; '))
>>> for k, v in cookies: driver.add_cookie({'name': k, 'value': v})
```